# Detecting touch on live area of UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to detect touch on live area of camera using UIImagePickerController. I want to track touches. Every touch event gets properly called except for touchesbegan:

How do I achieve this?

Any help?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The solution is given in below link.

http://www.pushplay.net/2010/03/one-tap-uiimagepickercontroller-iphone-camera/